# Read only role in Google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

I am trying to assign a global read only access to all resources in Google cloud for service account. Is there any pre defined role available from Google cloud?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not a predefined role that covers all resources. The closest is [Viewer](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#basic) but that role does not cover all resources in Google Cloud.

You must create a custom role and keep that custom role up to date as Google releases new services and updates existing ones.

Comment: thanks for letting me know. This is awkward, azure and AWS do provide it as a delivered role. This is need of the hour.